# Merge a Laravel array of Collections, and add new properties/attributes

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have a collection array of 'Products', as seen from the dump below.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#918 ▼
    #items: array:12 [▼
      0 => App\Product {#934 ▶}
      1 => App\Product {#943 ▶}
      2 => App\Product {#959 ▶}
      3 => App\Product {#968 ▶}
      4 => App\Product {#984 ▶}
      5 => App\Product {#993 ▶}
      6 => App\Product {#1009 ▶}
      7 => App\Product {#1018 ▶}
      8 => App\Product {#1034 ▶}
      9 => App\Product {#1043 ▶}
      10 => App\Product {#1059 ▶}
      11 => App\Product {#1068 ▶}
    ]
  }
```

This array has ONLY two unique products;

```
App\Product {#934 ▼
   ...
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "slug" => "26027686555545"
    "details" => App\DispatchStock {#900 ▼
        ...
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        ...
        "quantity" => 3
        "created_at" => "2020-05-04 15:56:07"
      ]
      ...
    }
  ]
...
}
```

and

```
App\Product {#943 ▼
    ...
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:10 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "slug" => "26027687444410"
      "details" => App\DispatchStock {#899 ▼
        ...
        #attributes: array:9 [▼
          ...
          "quantity" => 5
          "created_at" => "2020-05-04 15:56:07"
        ]
        ...
      }
    ]
    ...
  }
```

duplicated 6 times each (with varying 'quantity's).
I want to loop through the collection array of 'Products', merge all the duplicates, and return an array of just the unique products.
And have something like:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#918 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => App\Product {#934 ▶}
      1 => App\Product {#943 ▶}
    ]
  }
```

While appending a new attribute 'combined_available_quantity' (the sum of all the 'quantity's of the Products) to the 'details' property of each of the unique Products.
For example, I want one of the final 'Product's to look like:

```
App\Product {#943 ▼
    ...
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:10 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "slug" => "26027687444410"
      "details" => App\DispatchStock {#899 ▼
        ...
        #attributes: array:9 [▼
          ...
          "quantity" => 5
          "created_at" => "2020-05-04 15:56:07"
          "combined_available_quantity" => 27
        ]
        ...
      }
    ]
    ...
  }
```

I already started with the code below.

```
...
$combinedProducts = collect();
foreach ($products as $product) {

    $combinedProducts = $combinedProducts->each(function($combinedProduct) use ($combinedProducts, $product) {
                            if ($combinedProduct->slug == $product->slug) {
                                $qty = $product->details->quantity + $combinedProduct->details->quantity;
                                $combinedProduct->details->setAttribute('combined_available_quantity', $qty);
                            } else {
                                $product->details->setAttribute('combined_available_quantity', $product->details->quantity);
                                $combinedProducts->push($product);
                            }
                        });

    $combinedProducts = $combinedProducts->values();
}
```

But it's buggy, and doesn't give me required results.
I need a better approach. Thanks.

Comment: Then why not fix that code? Without knowing **why** that fails, its impossible to provide help

Comment: @NicoHaase, I didn't get required results obviously due to how I implemented those loops. I knew this, but didn't have the luxury of time to continue debugging alone. Hence why I asked for a "better approach".

Answer (score 1):

```
$collect->groupBy('slug')->map(function($item){
    return $item->sum('quantity');
})
```

Comment: Thanks Ramiz. I hadn't really explored the use of the "groupBy" and "map" functions before now. They were exactly what I needed. I've edited your answer to show how I resolved my issue.